# How to use this attributes in my custom form ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, column

How to use this attributes in my custom form ui component

[image]

Comment: explain more about ur issue

Comment: i want use this attribute in page product's column controls. my custom grid, i used <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/> but it not working

Comment: your question is not clear, these are some columns which you create through UI Component. some of them are not visible by default because. so you can show them from this menu.